# Acceder al contenido de un TitledPane en JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Quiero acceder a todos los nodos que están contenidos en un `TitledPane` para lo cual hago un bucle:

```
for ( Node panel :  panelTitulado.getChildren()){                  
             System.out.println ("Nodo: " + panel.toString());                      
         }
```

Este procedimiento funciona para contenedores como VBox pero no para `TitledPane` ya que no existe la propiedad `getChildren()` ¿Hay alguna propiedad que permita acceder al contenido para conocer todos los nodos allí dentro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar `getContent()`, por ejemplo:

```
for ( Node panel :  panelTitulado.getContent()){                  
             System.out.println ("Nodo: " + panel.toString());                      
    }
```

Es importante realizar el casting del tipo de contenedor que regularmente es `AnchorPane` :

```
for ( Node panel:  ((AnchorPane) panelTitulado.getContent()).getChildren()){
            System.out.println ("Nodo: " + panel.toString());
            System.out.println ("Nodo Id : " + panel.getId().toString());
        }
```

De esta forma puedes obtener la información de los nodos contenidos dentro del `TitledPane`

```
Nodo: Main$3[id=id1]
Nodo id: id1
Nodo: Main$4[id=id2]
Nodo id: id2
Nodo: Main$5[id=id3]
Nodo id: id3
Nodo: Main$6[id=id4]
Nodo id: id4
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres acceder a todos los nodos de un `TitledPane`, debes primero obtener el contenido de este, seguidamente realizar un `casting` del `Node` obtenido al tipo específico de `layout` establecido y sobre este invocar `getChildren`.

Supon que hemos creado el contenido de nuestro `TitlePane` así:

```
TitledPane panelTitulado = new TitledPane();

AnchorPane miLayout = new AnchorPane();
miLayout.getChildren().add(miNodo1);
miLayout.getChildren().add(miNodo2);
myLayout.getChildren().add(miNodon);

panelTitulado.setContent(myLayout);
```

Ahora, el proceso inverso sería:

```
AnchorPane myLayout = (AnchorPane) panelTitulado.getContent();
myLayout.getChildren().forEach((Node panel) -> {
    System.out.println ("Nodo: " + panel.toString());
});
```

Ten presente que para obtener los nodos de myLayout utilizo el método [forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635398/java-8-iterable-foreach-vs-foreach-loop) junto con una expresión [lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) habilitadas a partir de la versión 8 de java.